# query works in ssms but not in ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssrs-2012

So the problem I am having has got me completely perplexed. I have a dataset that uses a query with 4 parameters. There are the regular choices the users can choose for the different parameters, except for one choice which is ' ALL' which if the user chooses will choose everything.

I run the SSRS report and for some reason when on only one of the parameters the user chooses ' ALL' it returns no records, just a blank table. I try to recreate the same query behind the dataset on SSMS and input the ' ALL' option in that same problem parameter and it returns all the records I expected to see.

Query:

```
Declare @workingParam1 as varchar(200)
Declare @workingParam2 as varchar(50)
Declare @workingParam3 as varchar(50)
Declare @problemParam as varchar(50) -- this one is giving me problems only 
                                     -- if I choose ' ALL'


SELECT        Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9
FROM            View
WHERE        
(Col1 = @problemParam OR @problemParam = ' ALL') And 
(Col2 = @workingParam1 OR @workingParam1  = ' ALL') And
(Col3 = @workingParam2 OR @workingParam2 = ' ALL') And 
(Col4 = @workingParam3 OR @workingParam3 = ' ALL')
ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if there is maybe any setting to change this in SQL Server and you've maybe used that, but normally `'%' = <somehting not '%'>` is false and I guess your `[field]` isn't equal to `'%'`. Maybe you want to use `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: oops i did put like instead of = i am typing this from memory, i ill edit the question

Comment: Darryl, I think you've changed the wrong one (in the `WHEN` instead of the one left of the `CASE`)... ;)

Comment: gahh..thanks man! I just edited now that I have access to my query and updated it using M. Ali's version as it seems cleaner

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have a multi-select parameter in your SSRS report. When you select `ALL` from the parameter drop down list in ssrs report, it does not pass your t-sql query a value of literal string `All` but it passes all the values to your t-sql in a comma delimited list, `'1,2,3,4'`.

Now you have to make changes to your T-SQL code, so it can handle parameters passed as a comma delimited list.

There are many question on Stack Overflow on that matter.

Alternatively you can create your on `Select All` value to show in your parameter drop down, only then you can use the logic you have used in your current query, but even then I would use something like...

```
WHERE (ColumnName = @Param OR @Param = 'All')
```

This will get your desired results but again if you want better performance from your t-sql code, use a stored procedure for your data set and use dynamic sql to filter out the `Where` clause altogether if the user passes `All` parameter.

A lot of information in this short answer and a lot of googling for you to do :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. The parameters are all single select. I tried using your where clause. I seem to get the same problem if @problemParameter is selected with the ' ALL' value it returns no records. However the other 3 parameters when I choose ' ALL' it works fine. I will go down the SP route to see if I can get better luck with that. Thanks!